# How to hide previous week line

Tags: pivot, line, hide

I would like to hide previous week line which are coming on chart.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp3b1.jpg)

Comment: You should share you code in code blocks (``` your code ```). Sharing as an image does not help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Step 1. Script settings
 study(title="Pivot Point", overlay=true)

 // Input settings
 // Create a pull-down menu for the pivot type
 pivotType = input(title="Pivot Type", options=["Weekly"], defval="Weekly")


 // Make toggles for pivot level options
 plotPP   = input(title="Plot PP", type=bool, defval=true)
 plotS1R1 = input(title="Plot S1 and R1", type=bool, defval=true)
 plotS2R2 = input(title="Plot S2 and R2", type=bool, defval=true)
 plotS3R3 = input(title="Plot S3 and R3", type=bool, defval=true)



// Step 2. Calculate indicator values
// Create a function to fetch daily and weekly data
 GetData(res, data) =>
 security(tickerid, res, data[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)


// Fetch weekly price data


 weeklyHigh  = GetData("W", high)
 weeklyLow   = GetData("W", low)
 weeklyClose = GetData("W", close)


// Now figure out which kind of price data
// to use for the pivot calculation
theHigh = weeklyHigh

theLow =  weeklyLow

theClose = weeklyClose

// Finally calculate the pivot levels
pp = (theHigh + theLow + 2*theClose) / 4

r1 = (pp * 2) - theLow
s1 = (pp * 2) - theHigh
r2 = (pp - s1) + r1
s2 = pp - (r1 - s1)
r3 = (pp - s1) + r2
s3 = pp - (r2 - s1)

// Step 3. Output indicator data
// Plot the various pivot levels
plot(r3, title="R3", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)

plot(r2, title="R2", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)

plot(r1, title="R1", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)

plot(pp, title="PP", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)

plot(s1, title="S1", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)

plot(s2, title="S2", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)

plot(s3, title="S3", style=line, linewidth=1, color=black)
```

Comment: Please help me to hide previous plotted lines